# Installing of package flight always ends with error 0x87E107D6

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to use the feature "Package flight" for testing my windows phone application. I created a new flight package and also a new flight group. The package flight was passed certification and successfully published in app-store. But when I try to install it from app-store I always get an error (error code 0x87E107D6) and installation fails. During installing there is a text "acquiring license" and then I get the error. The application is free and also when I submit the same package as a regular submission everything works without problem( it is installable), therefore I think there is no problem with the package. I also tried this on 2 different devices with windows mobile 10 and without any success. I also contacted windows support with the problem and although I've been communicating with them for one month but I have not got neither any explanation what is the error code means or how to avoid it. Do you know what could be the reason of the error?

Comment: You can try deleting your old flights and follow the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights#create-a-new-package-flight) to generate a new one. I cannot reproduce your issue so the best way is still to follow your support ticket request.
Would you please provide your ticket number so that I can help to contact the case owner and have the agent follow up with you?

Comment: The ticket number is SRX1357839285ID. I tried to create many flight package without any success. Also I copied a package from non-flighted submission and also without success. I have no problem with the live version.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I've solved it. The problem was caused by flight-groups. My "email" address was in more flight groups. The system allows to insert the same email address to more flight groups, but then (in my case) the package flight is not installable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by my account "email" address that was in 2 flight groups. I removed it from one and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

having the same issue... just added a flight package and can't install.Even uninstalling ad reinstalling the app doesn't work. But if I remove my account from the group to receive the flight, I can get the non-flight package without errors.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my phone from Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 920) to Windows 10 Mobile (Microsoft Lumia 650 Dual SIM) I am facing error installing my OTR-Master app since there is a conflict with a package flight app vs. published app!

It seems that MS can't imagine that a developer is using his own apps and need an app installed twice (one production version) and one test version (package flight).

**Conclusion/Solution:**
Can't be a BETA tester + user for my own app + at the same time with that new fabulous "package flight" approach.

Removed my email (Live ID) from the BETA tester list and now I am able to install the published app.

Strange: Still able to use the "packaged flighted" app ...